# Finding total sum by aggregating Redis JSON

Tags: redis, redisjson, redis-search

I want to find total website visits by summing up the visits of individual pages.

In my Redis, I have JSONs like:

```
{'page_name': 'home', 'visit_count' : 10}
{'page_name': 'add_to_cart', 'visit_count' : 7}
{'page_name': 'checkout', 'visit_count' : 5}
```

I want to run an aggregation logic using FT.AGGREATE so that I can get, total_visits = 10 + 7 + 5 = 22

I can add necessary indexing, if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FT.AGGREGATE` for that. You will have to index at least one field for that.

Here is an example using your data.

**Add Data**

```
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET doc:1 $ '{"page_name": "home", "visit_count" : 10}' 
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET doc:2 $ '{"page_name": "add_to_cart", "visit_count" : 7}' 
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET doc:3 $ '{"page_name": "checkout", "visit_count" : 5}' 
OK
```

**Create an index**

At least one field needs to be indexed. Here are few possible options:

1. Indexing `visit_count`:

   ```
   FT.CREATE idx ON JSON PREFIX 1 doc: SCHEMA $.visit_count AS visit_count SORTABLE
   ```
2. Indexing `page_name`

   ```
   FT.CREATE idx ON JSON PREFIX 1 doc: SCHEMA $.page_name AS page_name TAG
   ```
3. Indexing `page_name` and referring to `visit_count`(multiple lines for readability):

   ```
   FT.CREATE idx ON JSON PREFIX 1 doc: SCHEMA 
       $.visit_count AS visit_count SORTABLE NOINDEX 
       $.page_name AS page_name TAG
   ```

   Notice that I mention `visit_count` with `NOINDEX` for quick access but without indexing (so it cannot be referred to in the query part, but can be referred to as part of the aggregations).

**Querying the index**

The trick is to use some dummy field that is equal in all the documents. You can use an existing one if you have one, but if not you can create one using `APPLY` ([documentation here](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/search/aggregations/#apply-expressions)):

```
APPLY 1 AS __dummy
```

will add to all the documents a field named `__dummy` with the value `1`. This is only for the query context and it will not be added to the JSON object itself. Of course, any name and value are possible.

For cases 1 and 3:

```
FT.AGGREGATE idx * APPLY 1 AS __dummy GROUPBY 1 @__dummy REDUCE SUM 1 @visit_count AS count
```

For case 2:

```
FT.AGGREGATE idx * APPLY 1 AS __dummy LOAD 3 $.visit_count AS visit_count GROUPBY 1 @__dummy REDUCE SUM 1 @visit_count AS count
```

Output (for all cases):

```
1) (integer) 1
2) 1) "__dummy"
   2) "1"
   3) "count"
   4) "22"
```

**EDIT**

Apparently, you can `GROUPBY` 0 field, so the `APPLY` trick is redundant.

Use

```
FT.AGGREGATE idx * GROUPBY 0 REDUCE SUM 1 @visit_count AS count
```

for cases 1 and 3, or, for case 2:

```
FT.AGGREGATE idx * LOAD 3 $.visit_count AS visit_count GROUPBY 0 REDUCE SUM 1 @visit_count AS count
```

to get the output:

```
1) (integer) 1
2) 1) "count"
   2) "22"
```

**Using redis-py:**

```py
import redis
import redis.commands.search
import redis.commands.search.reducers as reducers
from redis.commands.search.aggregation import AggregateRequest
from redis.commands.json.path import Path
from redis.commands.search.field import (
    NumericField,
    TagField,
)
from redis.commands.search.indexDefinition import IndexDefinition, IndexType


conn = redis.Redis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0)

definition = IndexDefinition(
    prefix=["doc:"],
    index_type=IndexType.JSON,
)

conn.ft().create_index((
        TagField("$.page_name", as_name="page_name"),
        NumericField("$.visit_count", as_name="visit_count", sortable=True, no_index=True),
    ),
    definition=definition,
)

conn.json().set("doc:1", Path.root_path(), {"page_name": "home", "visit_count": 10})
conn.json().set("doc:2", Path.root_path(), {"page_name": "add_to_cart", "visit_count": 7})
conn.json().set("doc:3", Path.root_path(), {"page_name": "checkout", "visit_count": 5})

total_sum = conn.ft().aggregate(AggregateRequest().group_by([], reducers.sum("visit_count"))).rows[0][1]
print(int(total_sum)) # 22
```

**ALTERNATIVE APPROACH**

If you don't need to index the documents for other reasons, you can use a [LUA script](https://redis.io/docs/interact/programmability/eval-intro/) to scan all the keys and sum up this value. Scanning the entire key space might be slow if you have a lot of keys, but it will not require additional memory overhead and indexing time when modifying or adding new keys

Comment: By any chance can you also help with translating this in redis-py syntax?